# How to correctly plan a Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, java, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to make my first WP app and I'm running into some design problems as I'm coming from Java and I'm not used to XAML and stuff like that.

Let's say that I have a structure like this:

> **PluginBase** - a class which has to be extended do build a plugin.
>
> Various plugins extending the base class. Each plugin has to retrieve some infos from different sites (something like an Instagram plugin, a 500px one and so on).
>
> **PluginGraphics** - a class which has a `PluginBase` attribute and that has to use it to show the retrieved data. This means that this class will have something like a `draw()` method which will print on screen (on a GUI) the infos from a plugin.

Here's some short pseudocode

```
abstract class PluginBase{
    string pluginName;
    string apiURL;
    abstract Image getImage();
}
class InstagramPlugin extends PluginBase{
    public InstagramPlugin(){
        pluginName = "Instagram";
        apiURL = "http://...";
    }
    Image getImage(){
        return new Image(apiURL + "/img.png");
    }
}
class PluginGraphics(){
    PluginBase plugin;
    public PluginGraphics(PluginBase plugin){
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }
    void draw(){
        super.draw(plugin.getImage());
    }
}
```

This is how I would do in Java when I need to build a custom GUI component which has to work with custom code behind.
It's pretty simple, I define the code and then I make a "GUI" class which takes data from the component and displays it.

Using this method allows me to focus just on the graphical part because, when the `PluginGraphics` class is made, it will do all the stuff by itself without forcing me to manually update the component everytime that the image changes. (provided that the `getImage()` pulls a random one from the site.

So I can work with a GUI builder and consider my component as a "blackbox" which just works, without having to know how it works.

The question is:
how can I do something like that with C#/XAML?

Does this kind of planning actually make sense on C#/XAML or do I have to think my app in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Java and WPF(XAML)-based applications are very different.  It is possible to do a very large portion of your actual development in the XAML itself using the MVVM pattern rather than in C# code.  I think you should spend some time learning how WPF works before you dive in.

Comment: about WPF?  I learned incrementally, but there are several resources online. here's one  http://wpftutorial.net/LearnWPFin14Days.html